# JavaScript Scope : please explain me why different result in and of loop creating variable

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, scope

Can you please explain to my why i get to different results;

This is the finished code and the result I wished:

```
function largest_of_arrs(arr){
  var largest_arr = [];
  var holder;
  var max = 1;
  for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    var sum = 0;
    for(var j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++){
      sum += arr[i][j];
      if(sum > max) {
        max = sum;
        largest_arr  = arr[i];
      }
    }
  }
  return largest_arr;
}

var array_1 = [[1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,2,3,1],[11,12,23,45,88],[20,20,5,5,1]];
largest_of_arrs(array_1);
```

This gives me the wished result: `[11,12,23,45,88]`

But when i declare the sum variable outside the for loop like this

```
function largest_of_arrs(arr){
  var largest_arr = [];
  var holder;
  var max = 1;
  var sum = 0;
  for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){

    for(var j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++){
      sum += arr[i][j];
      if(sum > max) {
        max = sum;
        largest_arr  = arr[i];
      }
    }
  }
  return largest_arr;
}

var array_1 = [[1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,2,3,1],[11,12,23,45,88],[20,20,5,5,1]];
largest_of_arrs(array_1);
```

The result is: `[20,20,5,5,1]`

Can you please explain to me why ?, and how to scope here works? 
if possible please with pictures (graphical) ..

Comment: Because in your true case, you set `sum=0` at the begining of first for iteration. So imaging sum going to 0 at each i, while in the latter, it just accumulates ;)

Comment: @Levo96 search for you logical failure like in mathematics 3+2*5 is not the same like (3+2)*5

Answer (score 0):

> Can you please explain to me why?

In the first case, you reset the value of *sum* to zero on each iteration of the outer loop. In the second case, you don't so *sum* just keeps accumulating.

> and how to scope here works?

Variables declared with *var* have function scope (or global if declared globally). Your problem isn't to do with scope, it's because of where you assign `0` to *sum*.

> if possible please with pictures (graphical)

Sorry, no pictures. :-(

Answer (score 0):

```
First Case - 
i=0
  sum = 0;
  j iterates till end of loop 
  sum = 1+2+3+4+5;
i=1
  sum = 0;
  j iterates till end of loop 
  sum = 1+2+2+3+1;
i=2
  sum = 0;
  j iterates till end of loop 
  sum = 11+12+23+45+88;
....

Second Case - 
i=0
  sum = 0;
  j iterates till end of loop 
  sum = 1+2+3+4+5;
i=1
  sum = 1+2+3+4+5;
  j iterates till end of loop 
  sum = (1+2+3+4+5)+1+2+2+3+1;
i=2
  sum = ((1+2+3+4+5)+1+2+2+3+1);
  j iterates till end of loop 
  sum = ((1+2+3+4+5)+1+2+2+3+1)+11+12+23+45+88;
...
```

Answer (score 0):

The `for` statement does not define a scope in javascript, only functions do (as per ES5). 
Your problem is because the moment you assign `0` to `sum`: inside the outer `for`.

Comment: Note ES6 introduced differences: `for` statements support local scoping of variables defined using `let` (with a separate environment record for each loop iteration). Block statements enclosed by curly braces also locally scope inner variables defined with `let`.